# Backpack for roblox simulator game

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I need a part to be incerted to the character's body everytime they respawn
Here's the script I made:

```
local Backpack = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):Waitforchild("Backpack")
local Player = game:GetService("Players").localplayer

Player.Character.Respawned:Connect(function(Character)
    local clone = Backpack:clone(Character.Torso)
end
```

Comment: I'm just trying to get the badge pls don't dislike

Answer (score 0):

```
local Backpack = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):Waitforchild("Backpack")
local Player = game:GetService("Players").localplayer

Player.Character.Respawned:Connect(function(Character)
    local clone = Backpack:clone(Character:Waitforchild("Torso"))
end
```